# Getting difference in seconds from two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have dates stored in MongoDB using Date(), MongoDB uses UTC it's date type, and as a string looks like `Mon, 02 Apr 2012 20:16:31 GMT`.

I want to get the difference in time, in total seconds, between this time and the current time (in UTC).

I've tried this:

```
now = new Date();
current_date = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
end_date = obj.end_date (Mon, 02 Apr 2012 20:16:35 GMT);
d = new Date(end_date - current_date);
console.log(d.getSeconds());
```

This is displaying `22` for seconds, which obviously isn't right.

It seems over complicated too.  Maybe there's a better way within MongoDB or a correct way within JavaScript to do this?

Any suggestions would be great - thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use getTime() on the Date objects to get the difference in milliseconds then divide the difference by 1000;

e.g.

```
now = new Date();
current_date = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
end_date = obj.end_date (Mon, 02 Apr 2012 20:16:35 GMT);
var millisDiff = end_date.getTime() -  current_date.getTime();
console.log(millisDiff / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(end_date.getTime() - current_date.getTime()) / 1000`

`getSeconds` will return only seonds, but not minutes, hours, etc.